# ho to make responsive iframe, also the video in it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, responsive

[when the screen is wider][1][heres the image][3]I want to make a responsive iframe, it works, but the width of the video doesn't follow the frame, it makes there is a scrollbar at the bottom of the frame, how to solve it? thanks :)

jsx:

```
 <div className="trailer-container">
   {error ? (
    <div className="err">
     <BsCameraVideoOffFill className="err-svg" />
     <em>No trailer, or it may be a server side error</em>
    </div>
   ) : (
    <>
     {loading ? (
      <Loading />
     ) : (
      <div className="trailer">
       <div className="iframe-container">
        <iframe
         className="iframe"
         src={trailer.linkEmbed}
         //  allowFullScreen
        //   allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
         title={trailer.title}
        />
       </div>
      </div>
     )}
    </>
   )}
  </div>
```

scss:

that object-fit and overflow didnt work, and scrolling property is depreccated

````
 .trailer-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  .trailer {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

   .iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
   }
  }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JJq.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrOgH.png
````

Answer (score 0):

I have tried implementing your code with plain html and css. And I did not achieve issue you are getting. Check codepen: https://codepen.io/Nadir_Alishly/pen/yLxddpq

html:

```
<div class="trailer-container">
  <div class="trailer">
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe class="iframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K4TOrB7at0Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.trailer-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.trailer {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: well that, css code like yours should work, but it didnt , i thought it was because of the src, but that seems unlikely, thanks for answering

Comment: @amanda can you provide screenshot, that may help solve the isssue

Comment: okay, I've put the link above

Comment: I have replaced youtube iframe with IMDB one in codepen and the issue appeared. I think thats IMDB iframe thats causing problem it has some kind of fixed width, but I'm not sure.